# TLS terminating proxy between HTTPS server and HTTP client

Tags: ssl, https, proxy, http-proxy

It’s a common pattern to have TLS terminating proxy in your DMZ before proxying to an internal server using HTTP.

I want the opposite however: be able to access a HTTPS server using HTTP. HTTPS server is on internet, and HTTP client is within same LAN as the proxy.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you can use a forward proxy which is proxying client request that is made via http to online server via https.  As long as proxy trusts the SSL certificate that the internet server presents.  It's the same idea just on the client side.  You can use nginx to proxy.  Have nginx expose port 80 and proxy to https url.

Comment: Would that also allow the proxy-to-server connection to be tunneled over VPN, whilst the client is not on VPN?

Comment: Theoretically it should work.  As long as the client is able to access the proxy and the correct port and the proxy on the other side is able to access the server via VPN